# Select options not reloading after form submit

Tags: plugin-development

I have two forms. One for adding, one for deleting option values. Deleting and adding works, but I have to manualy reload page to see changes in select part. How to make theme apper after submit?

```
    <form method="post" action="">
      <input type="text" name="add" class="foo-add" />
      <input type="submit" value="Add" />
    </form>

    <form method="post" action="" name="foo-delete">
        <select multiple="multiple" name="foo-values">
        <?php
        $foo_values = unserialize( get_option( 'foo_values' ));
        $foo_values_keys = array_keys($foo_values);
        $i = 0;
        foreach($foo_values as $foo): ?>
          <option value="foo_<?php echo $foo_values_keys[$i]; ?>"><?php echo $foo[0]; ?></option>
          <?php $i++; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
    </form>        
    </div>
    <?php   
      if($_POST) {
        if(isset($_POST['foo-values'])) {
          preg_match('/\d/', $_POST['foo-values'], $foo_id);
          unset($foo_values[$foo_id[0]]);
          update_option( 'foo_values', serialize($foo_values));
        } else {
          array_push($foo_values, $_POST['foo-add']);
          update_option( 'foo_values', serialize($foo_values));
        }
      }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the PHP code that handles data at the very top of the page before you print that data.

Comment: I tried header reload but wordpress dosen't allow for this and rise an error

Comment: Second method works, thx

Comment: Yes, silly me. Header redirects fail if output precedes them. Edited the post to reflect this. Glad the other way solved it.